# C# Visual Studio, how to access value from appsetting.json?

Tags: c#, json, appsettings

I want to access values from appsetting.json file, my problem is also that I have in my project multiple appsetting files, not allowed to rename it, how can I solve that problem?
Maybe solve with relative path?

[**want to access from tst -> src/Api/.../appsettings.json**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnSdZ.png)
[**Properties appsettings.json**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcDTC.png)
Thanks!

Comment: 1) There is no "appsetting.json".  It's "appsettings.json" (plural, with an "s").  2) It's just a Json-format text file. I'd consider installing [Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm) from Nuget.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and what isn't working for you.

Answer (score 1):

.net core

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .AddJsonFile(@"<path to appsettings.json>");

var configuration = builder.Build();
//  configuration["TAG DESIRED"]
```

---

.net framework

```
 using (var reader = new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/appsettings.json")) {
        Settings appSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

Settings class must match your json structure

```
 public class Settings
    {
        .. List of props to be bound.
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

This worked for me!

```
var httpDirectory = Path.Combine(new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent!.Parent!.Parent!.Parent!.Parent!.FullName,
    "src",
    "ApiGateways",
    "Web.Management",
    "Web.Management.HttpAggregator",
    "bin",
    "Debug",
    "net6.0",
    "appsettings.json"
);
```

Comment: Enter code here?